How to Set or Update Cookies in Wix Master Page Using JavaScript?
I'm working on a Wix site and trying to manipulate cookies using JavaScript within a master page (masterPage.js). I've attempted to set a cookie using the following code:
export function text151_click(event) {
    document.cookie = 'CookieConsent=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}

However, it seems that the document object isn't accessible in this context. Can I use another method or approach to set or update a cookie within a Wix master page to be used as part of custom code? Direct cookie manipulation might not be supported in the Wix environment. Any insights or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
